# how to remove break lines between a span tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

it appears that my `<span>` tags causes a new line break inside my `<td>`. how do you normally fix this?

```
<tr>
<td> date</td> <!--date--> 
<td> <span class="icon1"> <img here> </span> | <span class="icon2"> <img here> </span> </td> <!--action-->
</tr>
```

[image]

**[update = added css]**

```
.icon1{
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background-color:#eb2960;
    display:block;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: A `span` wouldn't ordinarily cause a line-break by itself; what's your CSS?

Comment: hi, edited post to add my CSS.

Comment: Well http://jsfiddle.net/PjZcG/ as you can see there isn't any break lines is problem of your CSS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for the `.icon`.

`display: block` causes a line break before and after the element.

Comment: how about just removing the display statement?

Comment: Removing it means `display:inline` for a `<span>` element. That's ok and would work, too. In my opinion, `inline-block` is closer to the desired behaviour of a fixed size icon, which is what the `.icon` class describes. You could argue that this class is more suitable to be applied to a `<div>` - in fact, that's what I'd do.

Comment: Agree, a span doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
.icon 1{
    ...
    display:block;
    ...
}
```

**to:**

```
.icon 1{
    ...
    display:inline-block;
    ...
}
```

You had to know that display in block separates things with a line break... :P

As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjZcG/) the span doesn't affect to any element of the td.